# Gradient map on pictures with PHP

Tags: php, image, colors, gradient

I've seen some answers in relation with the question i'll ask below, but any of them has helped me so i'll try to explain with the rights words what I need and hope someone could help me.

I've grayscale photographies, with some really dark areas and some white too. What i want to do is to apply a "gradient map" (name used in Photoshop, see [this picture](https://cloudup.com/cXHTKFIRinI)) with PHP. I've tried to apply some algorithms to set the opacity based on the darkness of colors but this is just called "color overlay" and this isn't what i want.

I'm not sure if give my actual code will be really helpful because for moment i haven't some concrete thing to show you.

Thanks for reading and hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but you can add a gradient map with [Adobe's plugin](https://github.com/awgreenblatt/gradientmaps). It only works in IE10 and up, as it uses SVG filters to achieve the effect.